# How to use regex to subset character format's number?

Tags: r

I have sample dataset like this:

```
Show in New Window
[1] 84
Show in New Window
structure(list(variable2 = c("ea_level_dataset::constituency", 
"ea_level_dataset::constituency", "ea_level_dataset::constituency", 
"ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", "ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", "ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", "ea_level_dataset::ea_type", 
"ea_level_dataset::ea_type", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
"ea_level_dataset::region"), values = c("Kongola", "Linyanti", 
"Sibbinda", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "Rural", "Urban", "0", "4", 
"5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "27", "Caprivi"), mappedTerm = c("Kongola", 
"Linyanti", "Sibbinda", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "Rural", "Urban", 
"0", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "27", "Caprivi"), valueOrder = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    variable2 = c("ea_level_dataset::constituency", "ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016", 
    "ea_level_dataset::ea_type", "ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016", 
    "ea_level_dataset::region"), .rows = structure(list(1:3, 
        4:8, 9:10, 11:19, 20L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -5L), .drop = TRUE))
```

Now what i want to do is getting the number value(like 0,1,2,3,4) within each group of variable (*those numbers are character format*), and remove the words value (*like "Rural"*) in col of mappedTerm.

Could someone help how to do that with regex in R? Thanks~~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `if_all` to return only rows having digits by either detecting for one or more digits (`\\d+`) from the start (`^`) to end (`$`) of string,

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
   ungroup %>%
   filter(if_all(values:mappedTerm, ~ str_detect(.x, "^\\d+$"))) %>% 
   type.convert(as.is = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 14 × 4
   variable2                                 values mappedTerm valueOrder
   <chr>                                      <int>      <int> <lgl>     
 1 ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016             0          0 NA        
 2 ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016             1          1 NA        
 3 ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016             2          2 NA        
 4 ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016             3          3 NA        
 5 ea_level_dataset::ea_positive_2016             4          4 NA        
 6 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      0          0 NA        
 7 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      4          4 NA        
 8 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      5          5 NA        
 9 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      6          6 NA        
10 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      7          7 NA        
11 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      8          8 NA        
12 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016      9          9 NA        
13 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016     11         11 NA        
14 ea_level_dataset::households_sprayed_2016     27         27 NA
```

---

Or another option is to force it to numeric with `as.numeric` and remove the `NA` elements with `complete.cases` (will have a warning)

```
df1 %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(across(values:mappedTerm, as.numeric)) %>%
   filter(if_all(values:mappedTerm, complete.cases))
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your explanation @akrun~~May I ask the reason we use "~" before str_detect is because we want to tell R that this command will apply for multiple times for different rows?

Comment: this answer is co cool

Comment: @Rstudyer the `~` is a concise form for lambda expression i.e. `function(x)` in tidyverse.  You could also change to `function(x) str_detect(x, "^\\d+$")`